# MySQL REPLACE() in a set

Tags: mysql

So I have a table of banners, and in that table there is a field that tells me on which sites they should be shown, like a poor man's relational table.

```
Banner.jpg    | ABC,CDE,FGH 
Banner2.jpg   | IPO,IPOMON,IPOHLM
```

And so on. And I use `find_in_set()` to collect banners for a specific site.

Now, I want to write a script that replaces these values, say "ABC" should be "XZY". So I run this:

```
update banners set sites = replace(sites, 'ABC', 'XZY')
```

And it's a done deal. But, problem arises if I want to change "IPO" to "APO" for instance, since this query:

```
update banners set sites = replace(sites, 'IPO', 'APO')
```

Would result in this data:

```
Banner.jpg    | XYZ,CDE,FGH 
Banner2.jpg   | APO,APOMON,APOHLM
```

Which is undesirable. So how do I change just "IPO" and not "IPOMON" when doing a `replace()` or similar function? I would want a "replace_in_set()" function so to speak.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably don't want to hear it, but consider how much simpler it would be if there was only one site per row in a one-to-many table.  Failing that you need to force a match by using `concat(',', X, ',')` in the replace so you only whole (fully delimited) matches.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, I am fully aware of the benefits of a relational DB, and I use it many many instances. Yet, I do use these "sets" in some occasions and replacing them would be a pretty large thing right now, so that's unfortunately not an option right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a query like this. first it adds a ',' at the begin and the end of the set. Then you can change your set and TRIM remove the ','.

```
UPDATE banners 
SET sites = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE( CONCAT(',',sites,','), ',IPO,', ',APO,') );
```

Comment: Ah, this may just be the best suggestion thus far, it will fix it with one query, even if it is a bit more work in the DB-side

Comment: It's not much extra work from the DB-side to use a complex expression. It's far more costly that the DB has to do a table-scan to do this. You can't optimize finding matching rows with an index... which is another disadvantage of using a comma-separated list.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of the disadvantages of this approach, but it is used on smaller tables so I don't think your solution is going to be very expensive. Thank you, I'll mark your answer as solved

Comment: I presume it should be SET `sites` = ... ?

Comment: @Andrew Bone - thanks you. I have correct it in my Answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a nice/pretty way to do this. In order to have IPO as a singular and IPO as part of a list changed you'd have to do something like this.

```
UPDATE banners SET 
  sites = REPLACE(sites,
    IF(sites LIKE '%IPO,%', 'IPO,', 'IPO'),
    IF(sites LIKE '%IPO,%', 'APO,', 'APO')
  );
```

The more things to catch the more complex the `IF`s have to be but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much how I am leaning right now, only I do it in four queries:

Comment: This is my current "strategy":
`update banners set sites = replace(citynet,',IPO',',APO') where find_in_set(citynet,'IPO')

update banners set sites = replace(citynet,'IPO,','APO,') where find_in_set(citynet,'IPO')

update banners set sites = replace(citynet,',IPO,',',APO,') where find_in_set(citynet,'IPO')

update banners set sites = 'APO' where citynet = 'IPO'`

Answer (score 0):

You should have the tables normalized so that you can use an `UPDATE` on the field in which value equals your desired replacement. Take a look at this example:

```
/* create the banner data table and add banner.jpg and banner2.jpg */
CREATE TABLE banner
    (`banner_id` int, `description` varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO banner
    (`banner_id`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'banner.jpg'),
    (2, 'banner2.jpg')
;

/* create the website data table and:
   ABC, CDE, FGH, IPO, IPOMON, and IPOHLM */
CREATE TABLE website
    (`site_id` int, `banner_id` int, `site` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO website
    (`site_id`, `banner_id`, `site`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'ABC'),
    (2, 1, 'CDE'),
    (3, 1, 'FGH'),
    (4, 2, 'IPO'),
    (5, 2, 'IPOMON'),
    (6, 2, 'IPOHLM')
;

/* update the website data table to change IPO to APO */
UPDATE `website`
SET `site` = "APO"
WHERE `site` = "IPO";

SELECT * FROM `website`
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/207ae1/1)

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of the benefits of a relational DB, but that's not what I am using in this example, so this will unfortunately not help me at all.

Comment: So you understand the benefits, but you refuse to take advantage of them. Why?

Comment: I have many many relational DB's in my system and take advantage to them a lot. But in some instances, this usage of "sets" is far more convenient. And replacing all these instances that use sets would be a huge endevour I'm afraid, so that's not an option. Sorry

Comment: OK, so to make it clear for my benefit. You just don't want to do the work?

Comment: Correct, I am working on a site-replace script that changes these codes on all tables in the entire DB, not just this one table, and I don't want to have to change the backend code for some 12-15 functions just to make this replacement easier.

Answer (score 0):

DO the fact you ha a string the you could use `'IPO,'`

```
update banners set sites = replace(sites, 'IPO,', 'APO,')
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to match "IPO,", ",IPO", ",IPO," and then also do a `update banners set sites = 'APO' where sites = 'IPO'` - I was hoping for a tidier solution

Comment: I don't understant you final goals  show me the exact result you want

Comment: I want the final result to be "APO,IPOMON,IPOHLM"

Comment: Only if "IPO" is first in set, which it may or may not be. But yes, this seems to be the only way.

Comment: No  ... not only if IPO is in the first set bat each time you have the string `'IOPS,'   so eg; for `TIPOS,` you should obtain `'TIAPO,'`

Answer (score 0):

I gave a +1 to Bernd Buffin's answer, because it at least accomplishes the substitution without fetching the data into an application to split and rejoin the string.

The following doesn't answer your question, but I thought I'd post it here to benefit other readers in the future.

I tried to test the new [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function in MySQL 8.0.4, because I thought the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('IPO,IPOMON,IPOHLM', '[[:<:]]IPO[[:>:]]', 'APO');
ERROR 3686 (HY000): Illegal argument to a regular expression.
```

MySQL [changed their regexp library in 8.0.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility) and the new library doesn't support the `[[:<:]]` `[[:>:]]` word-boundary patterns.